# Global beforeEach and afterEach Jest in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using react, so before each test I need to create a container element. Currently, I have something like this:

```js
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import Form from './Form';

let container: Element | null = null;

// setup a DOM element as a render target
beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

// cleanup on exiting
afterEach(() => {
  unmountComponentAtNode(container!);
  container?.remove();
  container = null;
})

test('renders with a heading', () => {
  render(
    <Form heading={'Form Heading'} />, container
  );

  const element = screen.getByText(/form heading/i);

  expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

As you probably expected, I need to do the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` setup for each test file. Can this be made global(after being global, we still need access the to `container` variable)? Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalsetup-string or https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array

Comment: @Elias it is correct, but then I won't have access to the `container` variable

Comment: Well that's generally a bad idea, I would recommend you read this: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/avoid-nesting-when-youre-testing, but again, it is very bad to share variable between tests.

Comment: @Elias I don't want to share the variable... I want it to be redefined for each test.

Comment: Well then the pattern I liked you to should serve you well :)

Comment: @Elias No, because I need to have access to the variable in the test. FOr each test, it should be redefined, passed to the test and then removed again

Comment: Yup, the pattern does that. e.g. `const {container} = setup();`

Comment: @Elias ok great! Post an answer, so I can mark it correct and upvote it. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Question: You are never using `container`, what exactly are you using it for? Also when you do `screen.getByText(/form heading/i)` it comes from the "document", so there is no need fo `expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();`

Comment: @Elias `container` is used to render the form component into the dom.

Comment: AHHH! I see now! I should have read your code properly. You're importing the wrong `render`. You're importing the one from `react-dom`, which is not used for testing, but for actually rendering the output to the browser. You need to `import {render} from '@testing-library/react'`. See [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro). You don't need `container`.

Comment: @Elias thanks a lot mate! You seem incredibly knowledgeable about testing, how did you learn that? I'm really having a hard time with so many different alternatives just within the jest ecosystem.

Comment: Loads of practice. Testing UI is really difficult. I still struggle quite a lot myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't technically the answer to the question you asked, this is the solution to the underlying problem you have.

You are importing the wrong `render`:

> `import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';`

The `render` function imported from `react-dom` is used to actually render the result to the browser, not for testing.

You need to: `import {render} from '@testing-library/react'`. The testing library does all that container management for you.

If you actually need the container for anything, you can still do:

```js
const {container} = render(/* ... */);
```

But most of the time that is not necessary.